# Move files to another folder, including creation date in filename

Tags: linux, perl, shell, scripting

I am able to move files from one folder to another but the issue is I want the new created file in the new folder as its created date and filename.

For instance

```
/scripts/a.log
```

moved to

```
/log/8june2012a.log
```

Comment: when you ask question you should post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cp filename "`date +%Y%m%d`filename"
```

This copies **filename** as **20120608filename**. For your example this is what you want:

```
cp filename "`date +%d%b%Y`filename"
```

This copies **filename** as **08jun2012filename**. If you want move your file instead of copying use `mv` instead of `cp`:

```
mv filename "`date +%d%b%Y`filename"
```

Comment: It actually does not copy the file. It moves it. +1 for the short shell solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using a couple of CPAN modules this can be made straightforward. [`File::Copy`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aCopy) has been a core module since Perl v5.0, but [`Date::Format`](https://metacpan.org/module/Date%3a%3aFormat) and [`Path::Class`](https://metacpan.org/module/Path%3a%3aClass) will need installing unless you already have them.

I have taken your requirement literally, and this solution prefixes the original file with the creation date using `%e%B%Y` as the format, with upper case translated to lower case and spaces stripped. However this isn't very readable and the directory listing will not automatically sort in date order, so I recommend using `%Y-%m-%d-` instead by replacing the line containing the call to `strftime` with

```
my $date = lc strftime('%Y-%m-%d-', @date)
```

At present the code just prints a list of the files it is going to move and their destination. To actually do the move you should uncomment the call to `move`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Class 'dir';
use Date::Format 'strftime';
use File::Copy 'move';

my $source  = dir '/scripts/';
my $dest = dir '/log/';

for my $file (grep { not $_->is_dir } $source->children) {

  my @date = localtime $file->stat->ctime;
  (my $date = lc strftime('%e%B%Y', @date)) =~ tr/\x20//d;

  my $newfile = $dest->file($date.$file->basename);

  print "move $file -> $newfile\n";
  #  move $file, $newfile;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution in Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy 'move';
use Time::Piece 'localtime';

my $indir = '/scripts';
my $outdir = '/log';

# get all of the files in the scripts dir
chdir $indir;
my @files = grep -f, glob '*';

foreach my $infile (@files) {
    # get the date that the file was created
    my $file_created_date = localtime( (stat $infile)[9] );
    my $outfile = $file_created_date->strftime('%d%B%Y').$infile;
    move $infile, "$outdir/$outfile";
}
```

As an aside, I would format the date as `%Y%m%d` (yyyymmdd) as it gives you a consistent format and allows you to sort by date more easily.

Comment: `(stat $infile)[9]` fetches the modification date of the file. You need `(stat $infile)[10]` for the creation date. Or `use File::stat` and write `stat($infile)->ctime`.

Comment: @Borodin, ctime is not creation time. From **perldoc -f stat** -- **10 ctime    inode change time in seconds since the epoch (*)**

Answer (score 2):

Another solution.

```
use strict ;
use File::stat ;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $File = 'mv.pl';
my $NewFile=strftime("%d%B%Y",localtime(stat($File)->ctime)) . $File ;

rename $File, $NewFile;
```

Comment: Except that the question was how to move all files in one directory to another as well as renaming them to include the creation date.

Comment: The question reads **I am able to move files from one folder to another but..**

Answer (score 0):

```
use File::Copy;
move("a.log",$DIRECTORY.get_timestamp().".log");
```

Your get_timestamp function should generate the date.

Comment: thanks sakura
but get_timestamp function gives the current date i want date as the created date of the a.log file say it was created at 06june2012 and i process this script today i need file as 06june2012a.log

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a demo for you,

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=`date +"%e%B%Y" | tr -d ' ' | tr A-Z a-z`


for FILENAME in *.log
do
        cp "${FILENAME}" "/log/${DATE}${FILENAME}"
done
```

you can run this in your "scripts" directory.